# Convert array output to link

Tags: jquery, arrays, advanced-custom-fields, wrapinner

I have an array output by Advanced Custom Fields in WordPress. I want to output that array into a clean a element.

This is my output:

```
    <div class="related-project"
      <span class="vc_acf-label">Related articles</span>
         Article name, https://my-website/projects/article-name/, , 3054
    </div>
```

Want I want to achieve is following:

```
    <div class="related-project"
      <span class="vc_acf-label">Related articles</span>
         <a class="related-project-link" href="https://my-website/projects/article-name/">Article name</a>
    </div>
```

What I tried so far:

```
    $(".related-project").wrapInner("<a href='#'></a>");
```

I know, it isn't much... This also wraps the span element in the a element, which isn't correct.